# Undefined is not a function ImpressPages DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, impresspages

I want to create my own form plugin.I get undefined is not a function error when I add jquery datepicker to _header.php file in impresspages.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form role="form" action="roomjack/create_customer" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="in">Check In Date :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="in" class="datepicker form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="out">Check Out Date:</label>    
                    <input type="text" id="out" class="datepicker form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Book Now</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my script in _footer.php

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove jQuery - it is added by the core by default. Remove this line:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

If you still get issues, try remove jQuery UI, too. Remove this line:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get : jQuery is not defined when I remove 

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: If that's added by default then why I ge the jquery is not defined error by removing the above lines?

Comment: I have no clue what else you've might done. Here's a default installation. Open developer tools and check that jQuery is there - http://9856.cloud.impresspages.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your code above it's work.. Maybe something wrong with javascript your plugin thus making conflict.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form role="form" action="roomjack/create_customer" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="in">Check In Date :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="in" class="datepicker form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="out">Check Out Date:</label>    
                    <input type="text" id="out" class="datepicker form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Book Now</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```